# Space available but cannot be used

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, disk-usage, storage, disk-management

I am using an ubuntu18.04 machine with 1TB. Most of the space is available, and when I run  df -H:

```
S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
udev             8,4G      0  8,4G   0% /dev
tmpfs            1,7G   2,2M  1,7G   1% /run
 /dev/nvme0n1p2   251G   213G   26G  90% /
tmpfs            8,4G   123M  8,3G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5,3M   4,1k  5,3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8,4G      0  8,4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0        59M    59M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
/dev/loop2       554M   554M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/274
/dev/loop1        46M    46M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15177
/dev/nvme0n1p1   536M   4,6M  532M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1        1,0T   5,2G  995G   1% /mnt/sda1 
tmpfs            1,7G    21k  1,7G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs            1,7G    78k  1,7G   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/loop3        47M    47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15314
```

When I run `df -i /mnt/sda1` I get this output:

```
S.ficheros     Nodos-i NUsados NLibres NUso% Montado en
/dev/sda1            0       0       0     - /mnt/sda1
```

And when I run `sudo parted -l`:

```
Modelo: ATA ST1000LM049-2GH1 (scsi)
Disco /dev/sda: 1000GB
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512B/4096B
Tabla de particiones: gpt
Indicadores de disco: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin     Tamaño  Sistema de archivos  Nombre Banderas
1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  fat32                        msftdata


Modelo: SAMSUNG MZVLW256HEHP-000H1 (nvme)
Disco /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512B/512B
Tabla de particiones: gpt
Indicadores de disco: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin    Tamaño  Sistema de archivos  Nombre              Banderas
1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                EFI System Partition  arranque, esp
2      538MB   256GB  256GB   ext4
```

Running `readlink -f /mnt/sda1` gives me this output:

```
/mnt/sda1
```

You can see that `/mnt/sda1` is almost 1TB, however when I try to copy a directory or extract a compressed file with 40GB to `/mnt/sda1`, I get only a part of it copied/extracted, then I get the message of no space available. I use the following command to copy the directory: `cp -r folder_name /mnt/sda1/`

Comment: what is the exact command you're running to copy the files?

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the output of `df -i /mnt/sda1`.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: @pLumo I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: Your file system seems to be broken, you have 0 inodes total.... Please add output of `sudo parted -l` ? Can you reformat your drive ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question. Is reformatting the drive the only solution?

Comment: Wow 1TB fat32 partition. You can try a reformat, but I guess 0 inodes is "normal" for fat32, so that [might not be the issue](https://superuser.com/questions/647343/zero-inodes-even-after-formatting-hard-disk). Please still tell us the command you're running to copy the files... and please add the output of `readlink -f /path/to/target_directory/`

Comment: I edited my question. Which file system, apart from fat32 should I use when reformatting to get the issue fixed?

Comment: If you reformat the filesystem to use depends on what OS’s are going to be used to access the drive. exFAT is compatible with Windows, MAC, and Linux. If you are Linux only then I’d suggest ext4 unless you have reasons to go with something more exotic